# Counting records using whole SQL string in RedBeanPHP

Tags: php, sql, redbean

It appears that RedBeanPHP cannot take in an SQL query string like other functions can, and I'm trying to find out the best way to work around it.

Lets say I have the following query (simplified)

```sql
SELECT id, name, email FROM tbluser WHERE id > 5000;
```

Rather than return all the data and then count it, I want to ONLY fetch the count first (for pagination purposes). I cannot simply pass the above SQL into `R::count()` because it does not work with whole strings.

```php
//valid 
$count = R::count('tbluser', 'WHERE id > 5000');

//not valid
$sql = "SELECT id, name, email FROM tbluser WHERE id > 5000";
$count = R::count($sql);
```

I strongly prefer my query as a whole SQL string to reduce complexity in reusing it, but it doesn't seem possible. I can accept only changing the SELECT field, but I cannot break apart the body as it's too complex.

So next I was thinking to try just replacing the select header with a COUNT(*) SQL

```php
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbluser WHERE id > 5000";

//this doesn't exactly work, it returns 1 rather than the actual count
$count = R::exec($sql);

//however this DOES work, but is pretty sloppy
$count = R::getAll($sql)[0]["COUNT(*)"];
```

**Any ideas on how I can either get `R::count()` to work (seems unsupported for whole SQL strings), or how I can get `R::exec()` to return the actual count?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `R::getCell()` to fetch a single column of the first row of results.

```
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbluser WHERE id > 5000";
$count = R::getCell($sql)
```

You can also convert the result of a query to a bean with `R::findFromSQL()`. Then you can use its `countOwn()` method.

```
$users = R::findFromSQL(""SELECT id, name, email FROM tbluser WHERE id > 5000");
$count = $users->countOwn('id');
```

This allows you to use `$users` to fetch the data as well, so you don't have to do two queries.

Comment: would getCell() be slower than the getAll() method for complex queries? Honestly I don't understand what's happening under the hood for them, and I don't have any easy way to use redbeanphp on lots of production data to get a valid runtime comparison. 

As for the second option, that wouldn't work for my needs because I need the simple count in order to do pagination (using datatables and SQL limits). I'm trying to avoid running the whole query for the user for performance reasons, so running it and then counting negates the speed benefit of pagination

Comment: I will say though, getCell is definitely a bit cleaner and does appear to give the correct result in my testing with limited data!

Comment: I don't think it will make any performance difference for a query that only returns one row.

Comment: If you didn't want to run the original query, why did you specify 3 specific columns that you're not even using?

Comment: awesome thank you! and to clarify, I need to get a total count first (i.e. typically that would be with R::count) that way I know how many records exist total. Then from there I can run the actual query with a limit in place for pagination. I'm trying to avoid running the full queries as they can take upwards of 10 seconds for the page to load, but for this I need a rapid way to count entries first

For now I will work with getCell and see how this does once I'm able to test with production data, thank you!